# Circle getBounds() method fails in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have:

```
const map = L.map("mapid", {preferCanvas: true});
//....    
const circle = L.circle([47.6652642, -122.3161248], {
    color: '#ea647f',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    radius: 30
}).addTo(map);
```

but calling getBounds() on circle fails:

```
const bounds = circle.getBounds();
```

It fails inside function `getBounds` in **Circle.js** which is Leaflet code,
The Leaflet getBounds method code is:

```
getBounds: function () {
        var half = [this._radius, this._radiusY || this._radius];

        return new LatLngBounds(
            this._map.layerPointToLatLng(this._point.subtract(half)),
            this._map.layerPointToLatLng(this._point.add(half)));
    }
```

Trying to access `this._map.layerPointToLatLng` fails
I get the error that `this._map` is undefined
Any ideas?

===================================================

Please Note: 
I also have a **polygon** defined,
and calling the getBounds() on the polygon passes fine and works correctly, shows correctly on the map.
=> It is only the `Circle.getBounds()` that fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `center` and `zoom` to the map.

```
const map = L.map("map", {center:[47.6652642, -122.3161248], zoom: 16 ,preferCanvas: true});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but - FYI - I used `center:[0,0]` and `zoom: 1` because it doesn't really matter, because after I gather all the data that needs to be shown I call `map.fitBounds()` and it overrides those initial values!! 
Don't know to explain this, but at least initializing `L.map` as you suggest makes the `Circle.getBounds()` method pass...

Comment: Maybe I can save someone a couple of minutes: circle.getBounds() only works if the circle was already added to a map. My hacky solution so far

`circle.addTo(map); markersBounds.extend(circle.getBounds()); circle.removeFrom(map);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the map state with `setView()` or some other mechanism. The `layerPointToLatLng` calls will fail otherwise.